# Android image didn't display to ImageView from image URL

Tags: java, android, url, imageview

I want to display image to ImageView from "**http://i.imgur.com**/4GLKF4Q.jpg" but The image in image URL didn't display to imageview. Can I do this?

AsyncTask

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            return output.toByteArray();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

in activity

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail))
            .execute("http://i.imgur.com/4GLKF4Q.jpg");
```

The image in image URL didn't display to imageview.
 in Logcat :

```
09-23 10:26:49.410 10591-10591/com.*** D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Comment: Better way to do this is to user AQuery  https://code.google.com/p/android-query/ or Picasso https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: This question has been asked many times but most of the answers are out dated. Modern way is to use NetworkImageView please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update from comment** : changing image server to another one solve the issue. I guess it's a **i.imgur.com** issue.

---

You shouldn't use your own image loader task, it will leak somewhere. 
Two good library exist : 
- [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html) (from Facebook)
- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) (from Square up)

There is also UniversalImageLoader (UIL).

Comment: I used picasso and result is same. Logcat log is  D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null . When I used different image URL, it worked. http://i.imgur.com - server isn't work.

Comment: Hmm I guess somethink is wonrg with this image maybe, try Fresco and see if t's happen too. If yes, it could be a software issue on your device

Comment: i used fresco and SimpleDraweeView . Logcat log is --- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: SimpleDraweeView was not initialized!

Comment: Don't forget to call `Fresco.initialize(this);` in your application

Comment: i call that code, app worked but still dont display image. with Fresco SimpleDraweeView Logcat log --- D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: as @TahaKörkem If think something is wrong either from the image, from the server or from your software decoder on your device.

Comment: anymore I using different image server, it's working. thanks for comments

Answer (score 1):

1. I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.
2. Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`). It also reduces OOM(Out Of Memory) issues. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an [official way](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image) to load an ImageView from a URL and that is NOT to use an ImageView.

> NetworkImageView—builds on ImageLoader and effectively replaces ImageView for situations where your image is being fetched over the network via URL. NetworkImageView also manages canceling pending requests if the view is detached from the hierarchy.

Images are automatically loaded in a background thread and the view updated on the UI thread. It even supports caching.