# Downloading images using volley image loader causes OOM error in android

Tags: android, image, exception, bitmap, android-volley

I am developing e-commerce android application and in one activity I have around 50-60k products and I am using volley library.
It causes OOM error after some image downloads.

Here is my code:

```
    if (image != null) {

            imageLoader.get(image, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    holder.image.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
```

And volley singleton class:

```
    public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton sInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private VolleySingleton() {

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(VolleyApplication.getAppContext());

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

            private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024) / 8);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });

    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }

}
```

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32734022/3140227

Comment: thank you. i'll check it out.

Comment: also check out these: http://square.github.io/picasso/ , https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader